# How to duplicate one special element in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 829
    "lat" => "26.5200389"
    "lng" => "128.0209283"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 830
    "lat" => "26.5197977"
    "lng" => "128.0213830"
    "right_angle" => 0
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 831
    "lat" => "26.5200101"
    "lng" => "128.0213830"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "id" => 832
    "lat" => "26.5199837"
    "lng" => "128.0217600"
    "right_angle" => 0
  ]
]
```

And I want find element have `right_angle = 1` and duplicate it in this array.

This result will be

```
array:6 [
  0 => array:4 [
    "id" => 829
    "lat" => "26.5200389"
    "lng" => "128.0209283"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => 829
    "lat" => "26.5200389"
    "lng" => "128.0209283"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  2 => array:4 [
    "id" => 830
    "lat" => "26.5197977"
    "lng" => "128.0213830"
    "right_angle" => 0
  ]
  3 => array:4 [
    "id" => 831
    "lat" => "26.5200101"
    "lng" => "128.0213830"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  4 => array:4 [
    "id" => 831
    "lat" => "26.5200101"
    "lng" => "128.0213830"
    "right_angle" => 1
  ]
  5 => array:4 [
    "id" => 832
    "lat" => "26.5199837"
    "lng" => "128.0217600"
    "right_angle" => 0
  ]
]
```

I have found this

```
function array_insert_after( array $array, $key, array $new ) {
    $keys = array_keys( $array );
    $index = array_search( $key, $keys );
    $pos = false === $index ? count( $array ) : $index + 1;
    return array_merge( array_slice( $array, 0, $pos ), $new, array_slice( $array, $pos ) );
}
```

But this function just work for one special item. If my array have 2 special item. The `key` will be wrong position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution:

```
foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
    if ($arr["right_angle"] === 1) {
        $new_arrs[] = $arr;
        $new_arrs[] = $arr;
    }
    else $new_arrs[] = $arr;
}
```

Voila, your `$new_arrs` will have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

consider, Array arr;
let int specialKeysCount = 0;

```
for (int i=0; i < (arr.size() + specialKeysCount); i++){
  if(arr.get(i).right_angle == 1){
    arr.add(arr.get(i),++i); //where ++i will be new position were              
                               object will be repeated
    specialKeysCount++;
  }
}
```

Hope this is what you want.